# anyone have any sample psd mockup files that i can practice converting to xhtml and css?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, mockups, psd

Basically, I'm looking for sample psd web page mockup files that i can convert to XHTML and css.  I'm new to web development, so I'd appreciate it if anyone provided samples thankx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of design blogs offering free psd layouts (e.g. http://www.themeflash.com/40-free-professional-psd-design-templates/). Try searching for 'free psd layouts'.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you find some sites that look nice (to you) and try to replicate it. Its easier than asking for psds, and you also have the "solution" in case you get stuck. This *is* practice right?

Comment: You missed the point...i want to get better at psd slicing and image cropping and converting to html..there is a lot of demand for that right now.